# React JS Input type text loses focus after keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jpm8888/fpxwy7t5/20/)
I'm trying to update the state array which contains an array of data objects.

State in constructor:

```
this.state = {
        data: [
        { name: "Abc", age: 12 },
        { name: "Xyz", age: 11 }
      ]
    }
```

Handlers:

```
handleName(idx, e){
        const data = this.state.data.map((item, sidx) => {
            if (idx !== sidx) return item;
            return { ...item, name: e.target.value };
        });

        this.setState({ data: data });
  }

  handleAge(index, e){
        const data = this.state.data.map((item, sidx) => {
            if (idx !== sidx) return item;
            return { ...item, age: e.target.value };
        });

        this.setState({ data: data });
  }
```

Render Method :

```
render() {
      console.log('render');

        const Input = () => this.state.data.map((item, index) =>{
            return (
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={item.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleName(index, e)}/>
              <input type="text" value={item.age} onChange={(e) => this.handleAge(index, e)}/>
            </div>
          );
        });

        return (
            <div>
             <Input/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

I know in every keystroke the render method is refreshing the dom, is something wrong with my rendering elements.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While returning element from within the map you must have a key assigned to them otherwise a new instance of it will be created always on a new render. Also you must not create a component within render

```
render() {
  console.log('render');

    return (
      <div>
         {this.state.data.map((item, index) =>{
        return (
        <div key={index}>
          <input type="text" value={item.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleName(index, e)}/>
          <input type="text" value={item.age} onChange={(e) => this.handleAge(index, e)}/>
        </div>
      );
    })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tpwbmhc0/1/)**

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't fix the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vcaq782p/

Comment: @ChrisG, you were creating a new component in render too. either directly render it or create a component outside of render

Answer (score 1):

Because on every re-render it is creating a new instance of the component woth values from state,

You need to take the function out of render or simply just use it like this

```
render() {
  console.log('render');  
    return (
      <div>
         {this.state.data.map((item, index) =>{
           return (
             <div>
              <input type="text" value={item.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleName(index, e)}/>
              <input type="text" value={item.age} onChange={(e) => this.handleAge(index, e)}/>
             </div>);})
         }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/m0hLu3r7/)